# How to install rosbash in ros-noetic?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to intall rosbash in ros-noetic ,but met a problem:

```
ylh@ylh:~$ sudo apt install rosbash
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rosbash : Depends: catkin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

ylh@ylh:~$ sudo apt install catkin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 catkin : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg (>= 0.4.14-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

ylh@ylh:~$ sudo apt install python3-catkin-pkg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-catkin-pkg is already the newest version (0.4.20-100).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

ylh@ylh:~$ sudo apt install catkin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 catkin : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg (>= 0.4.14-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

ylh@ylh:~$
```

I feel like it's a dead loop：the installation of catkin-python3-catkin-pkg-catkin ....
how to solve the problem?

Thank you very much if you could tell me how to do it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353177/how-to-install-rosbash-in-ros-noetic-?/) by [ylh](https://answers.ros.org/users/50326/ylh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2020-05-25

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-25**:
I believe you've run into the [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages). The correct package name for `rosbash` would be: `ros-noetic-rosbash`, not `rosbash`. Same for Catkin: it's `ros-noetic-catkin`, not `catkin`.

**Comment by [ylh](https://answers.ros.org/users/50326/ylh/) on 2020-05-25**:
Thank you very much for your reply.I tried it according to what you said, but it all shows the latest version.It didn't work.

**Comment by [Aysusya](https://answers.ros.org/users/55267/aysusya/) on 2020-05-26**:
I am also having the same problem, this didn't work. Are there any solutions rather then reinstalling?

**Comment by [ylh](https://answers.ros.org/users/50326/ylh/) on 2020-05-26**:
I am a novice, the principle of the error  is not clear, so I have no other solution.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-27**:
@Aysusya : please post a new question if you haven't done so already. If it turns out your problem does indeed have the same cause as @ylh's, it'll be closed as a duplicate.

Please provide sufficient information in your question: which commands did you use to install `rosbash`? Verbatim copies of any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it.I deleted all workspaces which be created before installing ros-noetic ,and uninstall ros-noetic ,then,reinstalled  the ros-noetic .Everything is working fine!

---

Originally posted by [ylh](https://answers.ros.org/users/50326/ylh/) with karma: 76 on 2020-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1